# OpenCV findContour method gives back "doubled" contour

Tags: opencv, contour

I have some really simple images, from which I would like to extract the longest contour.

An example image would be like this one:

[image: example image for contour finding]

I am using the exact [same sample code](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) from OpenCV's tutorial page. With one differenc I set the threshold to a fix number, namely 100.

The main line is this one:

```
cv::findContours(cannyOutput, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));
```

After I call the above function I iterate through the found **contours** and check which one is the longest, then I save the longest one. Under longest I mean which one has the most points.

In some cases, like in the above example image the longest contour is doubled. To make it more understandable what I mean under "doubled" here is a visualized image of the found contour:

[image]

So I tried to figure it out myself why this is happening by trying to understand the [OpenCV docs of findContour](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours), but I still can't understand the real reason.

What I manged to achieve, if I change to CV_RETR_EXTERNAL from CV_RETR_TREE, I don't get the doubled contour.

So my questions would be:

- What is the reason behind the doubled contour and why does CV_RETR_EXTERNAL solve the problem?
- Getting the contour which has the most points doesn't necessarily mean, that it is the longest, right? Due to CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE flag. Would CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE solve this problem for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: *What is the reason behind the doubled contour and why does CV_RETR_EXTERNAL solve the problem?*

A: OpenCV findCountours standard mode is `CV_RETR_LIST`, which outputs, for a line, as in your case, the inner and outer contour. `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`, as described in the docs, will outputs only the "extreme outer contours". Note that the outer contour does not mean the longest one. I would recommend you to loop through all the contours given by the `CV_RETR_LIST` mode and do your calculation.

Q: *Getting the contour which has the most points doesn't necessarily mean, that it is the longest, right? Due to CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE flag. Would CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE solve this problem for example?*

A: The first question is true, if your findCountours method is different than `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`. It is also true that `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` will solve this problem as it will "store absolutely all the contour points", but you can also sum all the distances between the points if you prefer to use any other method.

Comment: Hi Berriel, thank you for your answer. Just to make some things clear I have one more question. If actually what I would like to do is find the longest outer contours, then I should set the CV_RETR_EXTERNAL flag and from there I can calculate the length of the result contours by myself or I could use CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE and compare the number of points to get the longest contour from the results. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Actually, as `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` returns only "extreme outer contours", as described in the docs, you must be sure that in your problem any inner contours must be shorter. The safest/more generalized way is to get all contours (e.g. using `CV_RETR_LIST` as the mode) and all contours points (using `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` as the method), then you loop through the returned contours list and count their points (or calculate the total distance between the points). Ok?

Comment: Is there a way where we can change the density of points we are getting?

Comment: @AnkitKumar not by default, but you can always interpolate them